# elmah in azure webjobs

Tags: azure, app-config, azure-webjobs, elmah

does anyone know how to setup elmah in an azure webjob ?  The help section in the official website says it requires a few lines of code so this is what I have

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Log;
    ...
}

private static void Log(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (exception != null)
    {
        var logger = ElmahioAPI.Create("API_KEY");
        logger.Messages.Error(new Guid("LOG_ID"), exception, "An error message");
    }
}
```

I have an api_key and a log_id but nothing is being logged.  I have elmah setup in a web app and I have to enter details in the web.config, this works perfectly (logging to sql server).  The official help makes no reference to any settings in an app.config so how on earth does it know where to log the information ? Also they seem to have changed it so that you can read the logs from their website but how is this even setup ?  Its very confusing, can anyone help ?

Comment: Your code shows how to install elmah.io not ELMAH. elmah.io cannot log to a local SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

> I have elmah setup in a web app and I have to enter details in the web.config, this works perfectly (logging to sql server).

It seems that you have confused EMLAH and elmah.io. Here are [ELMAh and elmah.io differences](https://docs.elmah.io/elmah-and-elmah-io-differences/).

**ELMAH**:
Errors can be logged to a variety of destinations through ELMAH’s plugin model called error logs. Plugins for XML, SQL Server, MySQL, Elasticsearch and many more exists.

**elmah.io**:
elmah.io is a cloud-based error management system originally developed on top of ELMAH.

As you have said, you have an API_KEY and LOG_ID, then you could use the following code to write log in emlah.io dashboard.

```
[ElmahIoExceptionFilter("API_KEY", "LOG_ID")]

public class Functions
{
    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.
    public static void Trigger([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TextWriter log)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error from webjob");

    }
}
```

The log screen shot are as below:
[image]

For same demo about Elmah.Io, you could refer to this [github](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Functions/tree/master/).